# Coercion in Silverlight does not work

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, coercion

I've a custom control look like this:

generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="controls:MyControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MyControl">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" />
          <Slider Grid.Row="1" Name="slider" Width="120"
                  Minimum="1" Maximum="12"
                  Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                          Path=Value}"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

MyControl.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Value",
  typeof(double),
  typeof(MyControl),
  new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnValueChanged));

  public double Value
  {
    get { return (double)base.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
  }

  private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject source,
                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    MyControl myControl = (MyControl)source;
    myControl.OnValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
  }

  protected virtual void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
  {
    double coercedValue = CoerceValue(newValue);
    if (coercedValue != newValue)
    {
      this.Value = coercedValue;
    }
  }

  private double CoerceValue(double value)
  {
    double limit = 7;
    if (value > limit)
    {
      return limit;
    }
    return value;
  }
```

The TextBox is just a dummy to show the value.

Now when I add this control to an Application, I am able to set the Slider value greater than 7, although the value of my DependencyProperty is set to 7.

What I am doing wrong? Does the TwoWayBinding does not work in this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "I am able to set the Slider value greater than 7"  how _exactly_ do you manage that,  I've been unable to reproduce this.  The control behaves exactly as I would expect.

Comment: I would expect, when I am trying to change Sliders value to a value greather than 7, that it would stuck. This behaviour appears when I would add the slider in a normal application (without a custom control around it) and implements my coercion logic in ValueChanged-Event. But in my case it does not stuck at value 7. It is possible to set all values from 1 to 12

Comment: I've cut'n'pasted your exact code into a Templated custom control and the Slider sticks at 7, I can't make it go beyond that.  I can't seem to reproduce the problem you are seeing at all.  You are using Silverlight 4?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Did you take a new empty project for testing and still have it? I am interested if your solution would run on my computer. Could you give it me? If it's running, I could make a comparison, maybe I find the magic.

Comment: Complete steps for Repro added as answer, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps for my repro:-

- Create a fresh new Silverlight Application in VS2010 call SilverlightApplication1.
- Add new "Silverlight Templated Control" to the silverlight project, naming it "MyControl".
- Copied the inner contents or you ControlTemplate into the ControlTemplate of the themes/Generic.xaml file.  This Entire generic file looks like:-

  ```
  <Style TargetType="local:MyControl">
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                  <Grid>
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                     Text="{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=Value}" />
                      <Slider Grid.Row="1" Name="slider" Width="120"
                    Minimum="1" Maximum="12"
                    Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                            Path=Value}"/>
                  </Grid>

              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
  ```

  - Copied your C# placed in in MyControl.cs.  The whole file looks like:-

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public class MyControl : Control
    {
        public MyControl()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyControl);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Value",
  typeof(double),
  typeof(MyControl),
  new PropertyMetadata(0d, OnValueChanged));

        public double Value
        {
            get { return (double)base.GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject source,
                                           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyControl myControl = (MyControl)source;
            myControl.OnValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
        }

        protected virtual void OnValueChanged(double oldValue, double newValue)
        {
            double coercedValue = CoerceValue(newValue);
            if (coercedValue != newValue)
            {
                this.Value = coercedValue;
            }
        }

        private double CoerceValue(double value)
        {
            double limit = 7;
            if (value > limit)
            {
                return limit;
            }
            return value;
        }

    }
}
```

- Added an instance of MyControl to MainPage.xaml, which now looks like:-

  ```
  <UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
          <local:MyControl />
       </Grid>

   </UserControl>
  ```
- Run the solution, works fine.

Comment: Ok, now I have done it, like you wrote down. I added the 'Silverlight Templatd Control', copied all code. Unfortunately I have still the issue. Curious -.-

Comment: It's a little bit curious. The reason seems to be the debugger AND Opera Browser?! I've ever tested the program on Opera while debugging with VS. Never, really never, without. As soon as I disconnect the debugger, it runs well. In Firefox it works everytime. Thanks for your help :)